# Make text above the gradient

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

how would I have the text ("Welcome to Mane Frame Radio") to be above the gradient I specify in the css (jumbotron:after class)?

Snipp: [http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/l056a](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/l056a)
[image]

Comment: seems like your snippet isnt public; it ask me for a login when I click on it.

Comment: whoops. i fixed that. sorry D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the bg image on body like this:

```
body {
background-image: url('http://znc.mane-frame.com/static/silverleaf.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

then use the gradient as the jumbotron's background, like this:

```
.jumbotron {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 26, 2, 0.2) 0%, rgba(127, 13, 1, 1) 100%);
}
```

Now you don't need the `jumbotron:after` anymore.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I need! =)  I made a few edits by renaming body to a class and wrap the class around the jumbotron divs.